# How can I select options from dropdown and view result in table?

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and need help to use eloquent and pivot tables.

When the user selects options from diseases and data ranges dropdowns I want to select the respondent that was infected with that disease and the data ranges of when the respondent was infected. I want to show in the table which household the respondent belongs to and what purok is that household belongs to.

**controller**:

```
public function getInfected(Request $request)
{

    $SDOHs = SDOH::all();
    $categories = SDOHCategory::all();
    $HDs = HD::all();
    $diseases = Disease::all();
    $vaccines = Vaccine::all();
    $envHazards = EnvHazard::all();
    $puroks = Purok::all();
    $households = HouseholdHead::with('categoryHouseholds.sdoh_category')->get();
    $respondents = Respondent::with('household_heads')->get();



    $selectedDiseaseId = $request->input('disease');
    $startDate = $request->input('start');
    $endDate = $request->input('end');

    $infectedRespondents = Respondent::whereHas('diseases', function ($query) use ($selectedDiseaseId, $startDate, $endDate) {
        $query->where('disease', $selectedDiseaseId)
            ->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
    })
    ->with(['household.purok'])
    ->get();



    return view('filtered_map', compact( 'households' ,'SDOHs' ,'categories', 'diseases', 'vaccines', 'envHazards', 'respondents',  'puroks', 'HDs' , 'infectedRespondents'));



}
```

Respondent model:

```
public function household_heads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(HouseholdHead::class, 'household_respondents', 'respondent_id', 'household_head_id');
    
}



public function diseases()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Disease::class, 'respondent_diseases', 'respondent_id', 'disease_id');
    
}
```

HouseholdHead Model:

```
 public function purok(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Purok::class, 'purok_id');
}



public function respondents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Respondent::class, 'household_respondents', 'household_head_id', 'respondent_id');
    
}
```

dd:

[dump data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu4WT.png)